# HP charger converting 3 pin to 2 pin

Tags: charger

I'm having difficulty changing HP 3pin to 2pin. it has the same amount of volts and current but won't even show a sign that it's working.

I tested it using a multimeter it shows 19.5vdc and 3.85 A but won't charge my non hp pc.
I'm talking about the tip that goes in to the laptop. and I've checked the polarity and the outer layer is the ground, the middle layer is  19.5vdc and at the center pin has18.5vdc with 3.5A.

Comment: "3 pin to 2 pin"? You're talking about the plug that goes into the wall? The plug has 3 pins - i.e. it's grounded - and you don't have any grounded outlets?

Comment: "Won't charge your non-hp PC". Are you sure the polarity on the DC plug is correct for your non-HP PC? Are you sure the plug is correct? Not just the outer shell - is the center conductor is the same size? (It might not be making contact)
Does it work in a grounded outlet? Does it work with an HP laptop?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about an HP Smart charger.  I wouldn't recommend using this with a non-HP device.  However, if you'd like to change the plug to an older style, HP does offer an [adapter for this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003A0B56K).

[image]